# How can I point the Postgres service to use a different DB directory?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm using Ansible to install/upgrade PostgreSQL silently on Windows via

```
postgresql-12.x-x-windows-x64.exe --mode unattended --unattendedmodeui none
```

But this uses `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\` as the service's data directory. How can I now point the service to an different and "existing" data directory? So I don't necessarily want to do an `initdb -D I:\CurrentPGDataDir` since it already exists? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the service with `pg_ctl register`:

`pg_ctl register [-D datadir] [-N servicename] [-U username] [-P password] [-S a[uto] | d[emand] ] [-e source] [-W] [-t seconds] [-s] [-o options]`

For details, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html).

If you need to get rid of a service created automatically by the installation procedure, you can use `pg_ctl unregister`.

Comment: This registers the service as a Windows service, along with pointing to a `datadir`. Is there a way to point it to a `datadir` "separate" from registering it as a service?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. What is the difference between a service and a Windows service? Can you explain what you need to do in more detail?

Comment: They're synonymous, sorry. I do use the `pg_ctl register` command, and the PostgreSQL service shows up in the `services.msc` GUI. Is that the only way to reassign a data directory, via the `pg_ctl register` command?

Comment: The only simple way. You can probably also mess around in the Windows Registry... What's wrong about removing the service and adding another one that points to the correct data directory?